# Magento 2 modules - displaying images

Tags: magento2

I am converting a module from Magento 1 to 2. The plugin settings are in the store > configuration menu (etc/adminhtml/system.xml) and they have images displaying in the Magento 1 module in CDATA tags in the comments.

My question, where do I put these images in Magento 2, so that I can call them after compilation.  From what I am reading, my images should end up in pub/static/admin or something like that.  What location should I put them in and do I need to do anything else, like register them via .xml?

My module is in the app/code/... folder, here is a screen shot of what I am trying to accomplish:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your module folder you should put the image under view/adminhtml/web/images folder, the route should be:

app/code/Namespace/Module/view/adminhtml/web/images/image.jpg

after that make sure you run the command:

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy --area adminhtml
```

and in your template.phtml you could get the image with something like this

```
$block->getViewFileUrl('images/image.jpg');
```

Hope it helps!